# Sharing custom made color ramps in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, color-ramp

I've successfully created a custom color ramp in ArcMap (v. 10.3). From the Style Manager I can see the path to where my custom color ramp is located, but I'm unable to locate that path on my machine; it's like it doesn't exist. I would like to be able to share the color ramp I created with other coworkers, but can't figure out how to locate the path to the color ramp or how to share it.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: If the style saved in user\...\AppData\... . and you can't find AddData folder, type directory in a browser.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's my issue exactly. I'm confused by what you mean by 'browser'. Are you referring to a file explorer window? I'm using Windows 10 and tried typing your suggestion into the file explorer window, but it didn't seem to help as I was redirected to a broken web page.

Comment: What is the path that you see?

Comment: In folder options, check show hidden files. You can see these hiddwn folders and files.